# I get an error when I try to install my project packages with npm i

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I was getting error installing `expressJs` to my packages. I have had to do an `npm cache clean --force` no sucess, then I deleted my `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, I try to reinstall packages using `npm i` I still got an error.

Now I deleted `node.js` from my pc windows 10 and downloaded and installed the latest node and tried to reinstall the project packages again. Now the error I get is this

```
$ npm i
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ncies":{"autoprefixer'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Chioma Onyepere\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-28T20_26_29_676Z-debug.log
```

My app is built on nextJs

Here's the package.json

```
{
  "name": "ratethis",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "now-build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p %PORT%"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/infinity-web-development/ratethis"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/infinity-web-development/ratethis/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/infinity-web-development/ratethis#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "antd": "^3.15.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "next": "^8.0.3",
    "next-images": "^1.1.1",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "now": "^15.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "react-polls": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
    "shallow-equal": "^1.1.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "next-antd-aza-less": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: You can also try the [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: I suspect syntax issue in `package.json`.

Comment: I have added the `package.json` @IsaacVidrine and @go_diego

Comment: Where is `autoprefixer`? I was hoping to find a syntax error on or near that line

Comment: The issue might be in the `package-lock.json`, since the `"autoprefixer"` is not present here, either post it here or do a quick find in it and see if you can find any syntax errors (like hanging comma's or bad quotation marks) near `"autoprefixer"`

Comment: As it is, without `autoprefixer`, your `package.json` installs fine on my machine.

Comment: No results found for `autoprefixer`

Comment: Try deleting your `package-lock.json` and running `npm install` again?
I cloned your repo and it installs and runs fine.

Comment: You must have cloned the old version, before I changed the remote @go_diego. Please check the new link. I edited the `package.json`

Comment: @Chioma by new link you mean https://github.com/infinity-web-development/ratethis, yeah?  I cloned it, `npm install`, and `npm run dev` and it comes up fine.  I know you said you did it already, but I'd delete `node_modules` again and `package-lock.json` just as a sanity check.

Comment: Yes, @go_diego I  have not even been able to get the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` back. This means error is from my pc.

Comment: You are running `npm install` from the root of the project, right?

Comment: Yes @go_diego, from `master`.

Comment: @Chioma I'd hate to say it but, since I'm out of ideas, maybe restart your pc? As you said, it does feel like it is a problem with your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete all of `npm-cache` directly from my windows 10 pc, from %AppData%, ie `~/AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`. Everything works fine now.